# remove source path comment from __webpack_require__ in laravel mix v5 dev build

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

When doing a development build in a Laravel project with Laravel mix 5.0.9 (`npm run dev`), the `.js` output files are full of `__webpack_require__` function calls, that seen to import files from "resources/" folder.

But along with the actual path string, relative to project root, there's a comment showing the current computer's global directory path.

[image]

These is making my CI/CD pipeline, think there's changes, and perform unnecessary steps, even thought no actual code has changed, like when trigger a build on the same commit already deployed.

How can i disable those absolute path comments, and make build use only path relative to project root? So build stays consistent across different machines.

### I've tryed

- no variation of [mix uglify option](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/760) to strip comments worked out
- mix option `terser.extractComments: true` (or `terser.terserOptions.output.comments: false`) does nothing
- inserting `TerserPlugin` via `mix.webpackConfig` without configs, does a prod build really, plus extracting doc comments to separate `.txt` files, and id could not really figure out how to only extract the comments and disable everything else.
- set `resourceRoot` didn't changed the outputs (don't even know if should, but i'm 1h past the working hour, and no ideas anymore :D )

*ps. it doesn't happen on `prod` builds, but i do need to build as dev for staging environment*

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is not beautiful but it works (it is rather fragile, but should be easy to adapt to different environments), what I've done is adding a `postdev` [post-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts?v=true#pre--post-scripts) on the package that replaces the full project path with a single dot:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "postdev": "sed -i \"s:$(pwd):.:\" public/**/*.js"
  }
}
```

It is using `sed` inplace substitute with a custom delimiter `:` to make it easier to work with the path.